# Material UI V5 change color of selected row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

How can I set one of these table rows as "selected" or "active" and change the font color of the row to red on click? Also when one row is selected, deselect the other rows. I see examples for how to do it with more complex tables and previous versions of MUI but not with a basic table in the current version. Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

export default function BasicTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

edit: I think I need to be more specific. I have read the documentation but am having trouble applying it so that onClick the row is selected and the others are deselected.

Comment: `TableRow` takes a `selected` props. Try the documentation next time. It's pretty good.

Comment: Clever thanks, so how do I apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by setting the **selected** property.

You should hole a state for your selected row and then change it on onClick of the table rows:

```js
export default function BasicTable() {
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(0);
  const handleSelectRow = (rowIndex) => {
    setSelectedRow(rowIndex);
  }

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow selected={selectedRow === 0} onClick={() => handleSelectRow(0)}>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
              selected={selectedRow === index + 1}
              onClick={() => handleSelectRow(index + 1)}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Read more [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-row/).

Comment: This just selects all of the rows, I want to change on click and deselect the other rows so only one row is selected at a time.

Comment: @c011N I updated my answer. Check the new one.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. And what would I add to allow for multiple rows to be selected at a time instead of just one?

Comment: You're welcome. Hold an array of selectedRows instead of just a single row.